# Datatable dynamically created table not sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have few DataTables in hidden `<div>`s. This tables are works and sortable. When I insert this tables in other places of my page using `.html()` jQuery method (so I am dynamically copying HTML of each table to the other place) this tables becomes unsortable.

How can I force them to be sortable again?

Comment: `$("#myNewTable").DataTable();` this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initialization with `.DataTable()` has to be attached to something that is already on the page after the initial loading of the DOM elements.
Try `$("body").find(".yourTable").DataTable()` for initializing.
(If you have a more specific static container that contains all you DataTables at any point in time, replace `body` with that one for better performance.)

Don't use an ID if you end up having multiple elements with the same ID on the page, use a class instead. Otherwise the jQuery selector might only pick up the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var table = $('#yourTable');
table.clone().appendTo('#newParent');
table.remove();
```

The `.clone()` method, should clone all JS events with it.

(Be carefull, I removed the original table because you would have duplicated IDs, if its not the desired result you might need to change IDs with some JS)

**[.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)**